# Redirect exception handler?

Tags: function-hooking, winapi, game-hacking, exception

I'm working on a localization project and have a few trampoline hooks to translate some text in an online game. Periodically throughout gameplay, there are checks that run in the background to ensure the `.text` section of the game hasn't been modified. Of course I've done this with the existence of trampoline hooks, so the check fails and I'm met with what looks like a custom error code of `INVALID_CALL_1`.

I've attempted for months to figure out how this checksum is calculated, but I don't believe I have the skills necessary to figure this out, so I'm looking at other options.

I'm wondering if this logic seems reasonable, but would you theoretically be able to re-direct how the exception is handled using something like [SetUnhandledExceptionFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-setunhandledexceptionfilter) to check if the exception matches `INVALID_CALL_1` and have it return `EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION` instead? I don't mind doing the work, but wanted to know if my logic is flawed as I haven't worked with the Windows API all that much and am unsure where to ask this question.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what makes you sure that there's an exception thrown somewhere, as opposed to, say, an if-statement?